# pandas to_csv header vs columns

Tags: python, pandas

It seems that the pandas.to_csv function has two attributes which does the same thing.

Maybe I am missing something.

From the documentation:

> columns : sequence, optional
>
> Columns to write
>
> header : boolean or list of string, default True
>
> Write out column names. If a list of string is given it is assumed to be aliases for the column names

When giving either a list of columns, they put the columns into the order I specify.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2], "bar":[1,2]})

sio = StringIO()
df.to_csv(sio)
sio.getvalue()
',bar,foo\n0,1,1\n1,2,2\n'

sio = StringIO()
df.to_csv(sio, header=['foo', 'bar'])
sio.getvalue()
',foo,bar\n0,1,1\n1,2,2\n'
sio.close()

sio = StringIO()
df.to_csv(sio, columns=['foo', 'bar'])
sio.getvalue()
',foo,bar\n0,1,1\n1,2,2\n'
sio.close()
```

If I only want to sort the column order, which one is the *proper* one to use?

The only scenario I see where it makes sense for these two named attributes to be different is if I want to select columns, but **not** write the header into the csv file.

This would mean that using `columns=['foo', 'bar']` is the proper option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using columns, the column order is changed, both header and values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[1,2], "bar":[1111,2111]})
sio = StringIO()
df.to_csv(sio, columns=['foo', 'bar'])
sio.getvalue()
',foo,bar\n0,1,1111\n1,2,2111\n'
```

Using header, the header changes, but not the values in the columns.

```
sio = StringIO()
df.to_csv(sio, header=['foo', 'bar'])
sio.getvalue()
',foo,bar\n0,1111,1\n1,2111,2\n'
```

If you confuse `columns=` and `header=`, you're gonna have a bad time.